# Angular DOM Manipulation: Why ViewChildren works and ViewChild doesn't

Tags: angular, dom, components, viewchild

I found an interesting article [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/working-with-dom-in-angular-unexpected-consequences-and-optimization-techniques-682ac09f6866) by ngWizard that references a stackblitz example on the correct way to delete a component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <button (click)="remove()">Remove child component</button>
    <a-comp #c></a-comp>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  @ViewChildren('c', {read: ElementRef}) childComps: QueryList<ElementRef>;


  constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    console.log('number of child components: ' + this.childComps.length);
  }

  remove() {
    this.renderer.removeChild(
      this.hostElement.nativeElement,
      this.childComps.first.nativeElement
    );
  }
}
```

In this example, he uses @ViewChildren (so that he can log the number of children to the console).

I simplified this to just use @ViewChild instead like this below ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jrt32b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)):

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('c') child:ElementRef;


  constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  remove() {
    this.renderer.removeChild(
      this.hostElement.nativeElement,
      this.child.nativeElement
    );
  }
}
```

Unfortunately here's the result I got:

**ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.**

Why is it that referencing the first elementRef in ViewChildren works and referencing the single elementRef in ViewChild doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
   @ViewChild('c', {read: ElementRef}) child:ElementRef;
```

Hope that helps.